# What does String(num) mean?

Tags: javascript

I started learning JavaScript a couple of weeks ago.

So I was doing a JavaScript homework where I had to add a hypen between odd numbers.
Example:
input: 123233
output: 12323-3

I looked around for help, and stumbled on this guy's code

```
function insertDashes(num) {
 var inStr = String(num);
 var outStr = inStr[0], ii;

for (ii = 1; ii < inStr.length; ii++) 
{
  if (inStr[ii-1] % 2 !== 0 && inStr[ii] % 2 !== 0) {
  outStr += '-';
}

outStr += inStr[ii];
}

return outStr;
}
```

What does the String(num) in line 2 mean?
Also, why is var outStr  = inStr[0], ii; at line 3?
   I get the inStr[0], but what does the ", ii" do?

Comment: line 2 - creates a String from num, no matter what type num is.

Comment: line 3, declares two vars. outStr and ii. outStr is also initialised to the first character of inStr

Comment: lines 2 and 3 could be a single line - `var inStr = String(num), outStr = inStr[0], ii;`

Comment: You can't write any computer language without learning how to read and research in documentation.  A glance at the javadocs for the JDK would have answered this in a second.

Comment: Just copying someone's code is usually a bad idea for doing _your_ homework. Your questions show lack of understanding basic JavaScript concepts; if your teacher doesn't help you, why do you think SO will?

Comment: `javadocs for the JDK` ... erm @duffymo `java !== javascript`

Comment: @raina77ow - **everyone** uses jQuery - isn't that using someone's code?

Comment: @JaromandaX There's a fine line between using library and showing library as your own homework. But you're right, there was a confusion; fixed it.

Comment: @raina77ow - I'm sure he'll make the proper attributions in his code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX true - no coffee yet.  Point is still true.

Comment: @duffymo - agreed

Answer (score 1):

**What does String(num) mean?**
In javascript, **String()** means converting a variable to a string,
simply that easy...

Forexample   **var x=1212323.9; x=String(x);**

As you can see, it is the same exact mirror of **x.toString()**;

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

`String()` change something to string
example:

```
num = 7
//7
String(num)
//"7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look it up at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> The String global object is a constructor for strings, or a sequence
>   of characters.
>
> ```
> String(thing)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> `thing`
>       Anything to be converted to a string.
>
> [...]
>   String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without using the `new` keyword) are primitive strings.

So it's basically the constructor for the `String` object, but called without the `new` keyword so it returns a string literal instead of a `String` object:

> Note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and
>   primitive string values. (The same is true of Boolean and Numbers.)

A quick test in the Node console:

```
> String(123)
'123'
> typeof String(123)
'string'
> new String(123)
[String: '123']
> typeof new String(123)
'object'
```

In short, it converts an arbitrary data type into string so it can later do string manipulation.

---

As about this:

```
var outStr = inStr[0], ii;
```

... it's just a [local variable declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) that defines `outStr` and `ii`:

> The variable statement declares a variable, optionally initializing it
>   to a value.
>
> ```
> var varname1 [= value1] [, varname2 [= value2] ... [, varnameN [= valueN]]]];
> ```

It has the same effect as:

```
var outStr = inStr[0];
var ii;
```